# Get all Unique charactres from a column in table - SQL

Tags: sql

i have a reqiurement to find out all unique characters avialable in a given column from table

following is the content in a coulmn

```
SNO  NOTE_TEXT (column Name)
------------------------
1    Recovery for 1125.00 voided due to incorrect re-insurance allocation. 
     Now booked to 2 FR3270.
2    salvage cheque awaited
3    you. cdm_char_13  cdm_char_10  cdm_char_13  cdm_char_10 It is at:       
     cdm_char_13cdm_char_10 Walmgate Road Police Car Pound cdm_char_13  cdm_char_10
     Walmgate Road cdm_char_13  cdm_char_10 Perivale cdm_char_13  cdm_char_10 London 
     cdm_char_13  cdm_char_10 UB6 7LR
```

Requirement:-

Need to identify all unique characters avilable in NOTE_TEXT column
output shoud look like

```
A
B
C
.
.
Z
a
.
.
z
0
1
2
.
9
~
!
@
#
$
.
.
.
.
```

like this all avilabe unique characters from the table column

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using and what is the datatype of NOTE_TEXT?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
    [column1] [varchar](50) NULL
)
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table1] VALUES ('abc')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table1] VALUES ('acbd')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table1] VALUES ('cbde')
GO

DECLARE @column1 varchar(50);
DECLARE @text varchar(max);
DECLARE @i int;
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT column1 FROM dbo.table1;
SET @text = '';
OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @column1;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    SET @i = 1;
    WHILE @i <= LEN(@column1) BEGIN
        IF CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@column1, @i, 1), @text) = 0
            SET @text = @text + SUBSTRING(@column1, @i, 1);
        SET @i = @i + 1;
    END;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @column1;
END;
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
SELECT @text;
GO
------------------------------------------------------
abcde
(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

General approach: create a table of characters, 'CROSS JOIN`to your`Notes`table, replace the character from the characters table with the empty string and use the respective lengths to calculate the number of occurrences for that row, then`SUM...GROUP BY` each character.

I don't know Sybase DB so here's some Standard SQL (well, except for the `REPLACE()` function, which most SQLs have an equivalent of):

```
WITH Notes (SNO, NOTE_TEXT)
     AS
     (
      SELECT SNO, CAST(NOTE_TEXT AS VARCHAR(200))
        FROM (
              VALUES (1, 'Recovery for 1125.00 voided due to incorrect re-insurance allocation. Now booked to 2 FR3270.'), 
                     (2, 'salvage cheque awaited'), 
                     (3, 'you. cdm_char_13  cdm_char_10  cdm_char_13  cdm_char_10 It is at: cdm_char_13 cdm_char_10 Walmgate Road Police Car Pound cdm_char_13  cdm_char_10 Walmgate Road cdm_char_13  cdm_char_10 Perivale cdm_char_13  cdm_char_10 London cdm_char_13  cdm_char_10 UB6 7LR')
             ) AS Notes (SNO, NOTE_TEXT)
     ), 
     Characters (chars)
     AS
     (
      SELECT CAST(chars AS CHAR(1))
        FROM (
              VALUES ('A'), 
                     ('B'), 
                  --  ... 
                     ('Q'), 
                  --  ... 
                     ('Y'), 
                     ('Z')
             ) AS Characters (chars)
     ), 
     CharacterNoteTallies (SNO, NOTE_TEXT, chars, chars_tally)
     AS
     (
      SELECT N1.SNO, N1.NOTE_TEXT, C1.chars, 
             DATALENGTH(N1.NOTE_TEXT) 
                - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(N1.NOTE_TEXT, C1.chars, '')) 
                AS chars_tally
        FROM Notes AS N1
             CROSS JOIN Characters AS C1
     )
SELECT T1.chars, SUM(T1.chars_tally) AS chars_tally
  FROM CharacterNoteTallies AS T1
 GROUP
    BY T1.chars;
```